# load() without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get rid of using jQuery from my widget, having troubles finding how to replace load().

How would i do this in native JavaScript?

```
            $('#IframeABC').load(function() {
                var animator = new Animator('sWrapper');
                animator.animate();

                css('sWrap', 'display', 'block');


            });
```

Comment: animate() is also using the jQuery API, not just load()

Comment: @Swordfish0321: It’s a method of `Animator`, apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s… `onload`.

```
document.getElementById('IframeABC').onload = function() {
```

Or, to be more modern (incompatible? `;)`) about it, the `load` event:

```
document.getElementById('IframeABC').addEventListener('load', function() {
```

Comment: I don't think more modern is "incompatible" as long as you have a wrapper function that uses either `addEventListener`/`attachEvent`, one that does not want to use jQuery usually has a function for that.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Dunno… I don’t use jQuery when I don’t care about compatibility, usually. It’s a good feeling. :D

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent would be:

```
var element = document.getElementById('IframeABC');
var handler = function () {
    // Handler in no jQuery obviously
}
if (element.addEventListener) {
    element.addEventListener('load', handler, false);
} else if (element.attachEvent) {
    element.attachEvent('onload', handler);
} else {
    element.onload = handler;
}
```